# PHP file upload timeout

Tags: php, cakephp, file-upload

I have created a file transfer webapp, using cakephp, and it works fine if the upload speed pretty high.

Then for testing, I use a netlimiter to limit my upload speed to 50kBps to upload 45MB file, and somehow after around 6-8 minutes it stops uploading. Seems like it get to timeout. What should I do to prevent this?

my php.ini setup is:

```
max_execution_time = 3600 
max_input_time = 3600
memory_limit = 512M
post_max_size = 512M
upload_max_filesize = 512M
```

I'm not sure if it's because of php.ini or something else, but if I upload on high speed internet (5MBps upload speed) for 9GB files which will run about 15-20 minutes, it works fine. It just if it's slow internet speed, it seems like it does not work well

Comment: Have you checked if those are the *actual* settings that are used? It may be possible that (some) of those values are overwritten in a `.htaccess`, virtualHost or via `ini_set()`. Output the current settings via `phpinfo()` in your application just to be sure

Comment: @thaJeztah I did check that on phpinfo(), and it's correct

Comment: thought I'd mention it, just in case it was something simple like that. Unfortunately that wasn't the case. No other ideas at this moment, apart from the 'usual' checks to check the log files. Does your upload script use some authentication mechanism, e.g. A session-timeout? (Not sure if a session **can** timeout in the middle of a request?)

Comment: just  a side note: instead of increasing execution time, post size, etc., you could divide large uploads into smaller ones. See for instance this jQuery plugin http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: @nIcO I did using HTML5 to slice into smaller pieces (100MB) file, because mainly this file transfer would handle 2-4GB files. but just during testing I try to upload 45MB files on super slow internet (of course I still want it to work for smaller files) and it seems like does not work.

Comment: I meant *really* smaller ones ;-) I personally use chunks of 5mb, and a server side script to put them all together when they are all sequentially uploaded. Only drawback is that IE is supported only since version 10.